# Weird template constructor syntax

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

What is the difference between

```
template <class T>
class why
{
public:
   why()
   {}
};
```

and

```
template <class T>
class why
{
public:
   why<T>()
   {}
};
```

They both seem to work the same and compile.

**EDIT**

And, if they are truly the same, why is this functionality even in the C++ language?

Comment: They're the same. `why` is a synonym for `why<T>`

Comment: Well the secon one is... You know, weird as you said. I would like to know it too. So why <T> is there? What's the point if it's a synonym?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're equivalent. In the former, `why` is an *injected* name that's defined to be the same as `why<T>` (where `T` is the actual template argument.) This exists for ease of typing.

---

Note that this injection is into the class's scope, and not outside of it. Obvious, but given:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo
{
    foo x(foo f);
};
```

A common mistake might be to try and define `x` like this:

```
template <typename T>
foo foo<T>::x(foo f) { return f; }
```

But this would be an error, as `foo` in the return type needs template arguments. The `foo` in the parameter list is okay, though, because after `foo<T>::` we're in the class's scope, and `foo` is defined to be `foo<T>`. So the correct way to do this is either of these:

```
template <typename T>
foo<T> foo<T>::x(foo f) { return f; }

template <typename T>
foo<T> foo<T>::x(foo<T> f) { return f; } // equivalent
```